# Points arent showing on my chart

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I've got this chart in xaml:

```
<oxy:Plot Name="Plot" Title="Errors" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"> 
     <oxy:Plot.Axes>   
          <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" MajorGridlineStyle="Solid" MinorGridlineStyle="Dash" />
          <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" MajorGridlineStyle="Solid" MinorGridlineStyle="Dash" /> 
      </oxy:Plot.Axes>
      <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}" DataFieldX="X" DataFieldY="Y" />
</oxy:Plot>
```

And with a BackgroundWorker I do some magic:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    Foo.Add(new Point() { X = Foo.Count, Y = 5 });
    Plot.RefreshPlot(true);
    Debug.WriteLine("Added a point...");
}));
```

And Foo is of course defined as a proptery:

```
ObservableCollection<Point> Foo { get; set; }
```

And I init it in the constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Foo = new ObservableCollection<Point>();
```

But there is still no points showing up. My databinding should be valid?

Comment: Did you try without Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to check if the databindings are valid? Or Try Dispatcher.Invoke so that we can check if asynchronous calling is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I'll take it you're using the code behind, and accessing it from there?

I run a test in a WPF MVVM environment, similar code, without the `Plot.RefreshPlot(true)`.
Adding points seems to do nothing, until I zoom in/out, and then I can see all the points (so they are added correctly, but the view isn't being refreshed, which makes sense since I can't access it directly from the view model :)

I Prefer using code like this on my XAML:

```
 <oxy:Plot Model="{Binding MyPlotModel}"  ...>
```

and on the view model:

```
public OxyPlot.PlotModel MyPlotModel { get; set; }
```

Then I can refresh it from the code on the view model when needed.

### Edit:

Working code behind for above example. Have the Xaml code, and put this in your code behing ... it'll update happily ever after:

```
public PlotModel MyPlotModel { get; set; }

public your_window_name()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var linesSeries = new LineSeries("Random");
    Random rand = new Random();
    int x = 0;

    this.MyPlotModel = new PlotModel();
    this.MyPlotModel.Series.Add(linesSeries);
    DataContext = this;

    var bg_worker = new BackgroundWorker {WorkerSupportsCancellation = true};

    bg_worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {
        while (!bg_worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            linesSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(x, rand.Next(0, 10)));
            x += 1;
            MyPlotModel.RefreshPlot(true);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    };

    bg_worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    this.Closed += (s, e) => bg_worker.CancelAsync();
}
```